# Refresh on factoring out GCF, specifically involving smallest exponent on all common terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, fractions

I am refreshing before taking Calc1 and there is a sequence my instructor gave us and I am struggling to follow the fractional exponent moves he's made.  The problem is this:
\begin{align*}
5x^2(2x-3)^{1/3}&(3x+2)^{1/2}+8x(2x-3)^{-2/3}(3x+2)^{3/2}\\ 
& = x(2x-3)^{-2/3}(3x+2)^{1/2}[5x(2x-3)+8(3x+2)]\\
& = x(2x-3)^{-2/3}(3x+2)^{1/2}[10x^2-15x+24x+16]\\
& = x(2x-3)^{-2/3}(3x+2)^{1/2}(10x^2+9x+16)
\end{align*}

A) I don't remember ever being taught fractional exponents let alone taking the smallest exponent from all common terms (what does that even mean)

B) From the first format to the first equal sign, why was the problem essentially switched with the $5x$ etc that started the problem moved to the back, and then the original $8x(2x-3)^{-2/3}(3x+2)^{3/2}$ switches to the front and we lose the $8$ at the beginning and the last exponent turns from a $3/2$ to a $1/2$.  It's one of those notions that's on the tip of my brain but I'm still not making that connection.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to render the math thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you for that tutorial link.  I'm having fun learning the new Mathjax language

Comment: @Aryadeva understood and thank you.  I thought I had but after reading your comment I noticed I had omitted the $ at the end and also did not properly use the \frac command for my exponents. I'm still figuring out how to make a fractional exponent negative.

Comment: To type $(2x - 3)^{-\frac{2}{3}}$, type `$(2x - 3)^{-\frac{2}{3}}$`.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig THANK YOU

Comment: @BruceLeeKrager no problem type the expoennt when it's a fraction like this  x^{2/3} for $x^{2/3}$

Comment: @BruceLeeKrager  I reverted back to the edit I made earlier since some information (like the signs of negative exponents) was lost when subsequent edits were made, which would make it difficult for readers of this site to answer your question properly.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you so much for that edit.  I was practicing your last comment with noting a neg before a fraction exponent.  I'm still messing something up but with practice comes insight, so thanks again.

Comment: @BruceLeeKrager Just to clarify, do you know the basics of fractional exponents? E.g. if I asked you to evaluate $9^\frac{1}{2}$, would you understand what that means? Sorry if this comes across as condescending; I just thought it would be useful for future answerers.

Comment: @Joe thank you for reaching out and no worries on the clarifying question.  I do have a grasp of just the basics, I believe.  The $9^\frac12$ is the same as saying $\sqrt9$, which is 3.

Comment: @BruceLeeKrager  Yes, that is correct.  I will try to answer your questions, but it will take some time.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, good I'm glad at least the sheer basics are solid. No rush, and thank you much.

Comment: @Aryadeva I just saw your comment on cleaning up the notation for fractional exponents.  So it makes it look cleaner if I note it as: $x^{2/3}$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you so much for such a thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

The greatest common divisor ($\gcd$) or greatest common factor (gcf) or highest common factor (hcf) of two integers is the largest number which is a divisor or factor of those integers.

The most efficient way to find the greatest common divisor is the Euclidean algorithm.  For small integers, we can simply compare lists of divisors/factors to find the $\gcd$.  For instance,
suppose we wish to find the $\gcd$ of $60$ and $96$.  The divisors/factors of $60$ are $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60$.  The divisors/factors of $96$ are $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24,
32, 48, 96$.  Comparing these lists, we see by  inspection that $\gcd(60, 96) = 12$.

If we factor both $60$ and $96$ into primes, we obtain
\begin{align*}
60 & = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5\\
96 & = 2^5 \cdot 3
\end{align*}
Notice that $$\gcd(60, 96) = \gcd(2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1, 2^5 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^0) = 2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^0 = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 1 = 12$$ since $2^2$ is the highest power of $2$ which appears in the prime factorizations of both $60$ and $96$, $3^1$ is the highest power of $3$ which appears in the prime factorizations of $60$ and $96$, and $5^0$ is the highest power of $5$ which
appears in the prime factorizations of both $60$ and $96$.  Observe that the greatest common divisor can be found by taking the smaller exponent for each prime that appears in the factorizations of
at least one of the numbers, and then taking the product of the resulting prime powers.

We can treat variables like prime factors.  Hence, $$\gcd(x^3y^2, x^2y^4) = x^2y^2$$ since $x^2$ is the highest power of $x$ which is a factor of both $x^3$ and $x^2$ and $y^2$ is the
highest power of $y$ which is a factor of both $y^2$ and $y^4$.  Notice that in each case, we are taking the smaller exponent for each variable, then multiplying the resulting powers.

You were asked to factor the expression
$$5x^2(2x-3)^{1/3}(3x+2)^{1/2}+8x(2x-3)^{-2/3}(3x+2)^{3/2}$$
Observe that
\begin{align*}
\gcd(5, 8) & = 1\\
\gcd(x^2, x) & = x\\
\gcd((2x - 3)^{1/3}, (2x - 3)^{-2/3}) & = (2x - 3)^{-2/3}\\
\gcd((3x + 2)^{1/2}, (3x + 2)^{3/2}) & = (3x + 2)^{1/2}
\end{align*}
where in each case we take the smaller exponent for each common factor.  Hence,
$$\gcd(5x^2(2x - 3)^{1/3}(3x + 2)^{1/2} , 8x(2x - 3)^{-2/3}(3x + 2)^{3/2}) = x(2x - 3)^{-2/3}(3x + 2)^{1/2}$$

Recall the following rules of exponents: $x^{r + s} = x^rx^s$ and $(x^r)^s = x^{rs}$.  For instance,
$$8^48^5 = \underbrace{(8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8)}_{4~\text{factors}}\underbrace{(8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8)}_{5~\text{factors}} = \underbrace{8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8}_{9~\text{factors}} = 8^9$$
and
$$(7^3)^2 = (\underbrace{7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7}_{3~\text{factors}})(\underbrace{7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7}_{3~\text{factors}}) = \underbrace{7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7}_{6~\text{factors}} = 7^6$$

By definition, $x^{1/n} = \sqrt[n]{x}$ and $x^{m/n} = (x^{1/n})^m$.   Thus,
$$(x^{1/3})^3 = x$$
and
$$x^{3/2} = (x^{1/2})^3 = (x^{1/2})(x^{1/2})(x^{1/2}) = x^{1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2}$$
Notice that our definitions are consistent with the rules of exponents we stated above.

Thus, we can factor $(3x + 2)^{3/2}$ as
$$(3x + 2)^{3/2} = (3x + 2)^1(3x + 2)^{1/2} = (3x + 2)(3x + 2)^{1/2}$$
and
$$(2x - 3)^{1/3} = (2x - 3)^1(2x - 3)^{-2/3} = (2x - 3)(2x - 3)^{-2/3}$$
Therefore, extracting the $\gcd$ from each term yields
\begin{align*}
& 5x^2(2x-3)^{1/3}(3x+2)^{1/2}+8x(2x-3)^{-2/3}(3x+2)^{3/2}\\
& \qquad =  x(2x - 3)^{-2/3}(3x + 2)^{1/2}[5x(2x - 3) + 8(3x + 2)]
\end{align*}
I gather you understand the remaining steps of the calculation.